# Input button image disappears on submit

Tags: html, css, styling

I have a form:

```
<form action="/search" class="search-form" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <input id="q" name="q" type="text" value="Enter search text here">
        <input type="submit" value="search" class="search-button">
    </fieldset>
 </form>
```

With some CSS to style the button:

```
.search-button
{
    background:url("images/search.gif") no-repeat 0 center;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    border:none;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 23px;
    background-position-y: 4px;
    background-position-x: 5px;
}
.search-button:hover
{
    background:url("images/search.gif") no-repeat 0 center;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    border:none;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 23px;
    background-position-y: 4px;
    background-position-x: 5px;
    opacity:.8;
}
```

When I hover over the button, the opacity changes as expected.

If I click the button and move the mouse pointer away, the button becomes a grey square as the next page loads.

What's going on here?

Comment: What browser is exhibiting the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `active` state's style also this also:

```
.search-button:active {...}
```

> @Solution Updates:

Adding `:default` state fix issue.

Comment: This didn't fix the issue, though changing the `:default` styling did - thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @wilbishardis your most welcome. You can accept it, if it helps you. I am updating solution for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet seems to be working, so it is hard to reproduce the problem.

The rules in `.search-button` are inherited in `.search-button:hover`, so you do not need to repeat them, see below.

**Note:** background-position-y and background-position-x are not valid CSS properties.

See reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position

```css
.search-button {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/50x25") no-repeat 0 center;
  text-indent: -9000px;
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23px;
}
.search-button:hover {
  opacity: .8;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="search-form" method="get">
  <fieldset>
    <input id="q" name="q" type="text" value="Enter search text here">
    <input type="submit" value="search" class="search-button">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```